# Update react state without overriding previous state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state, dispatch, payload

I am trying to update a state value w/ a multidimensional array but I can't seem to figure how to update one of the arrays object key values without effecting the previous state value which I use later in the process after the dispatch call.
I the code below the payload carries an array of ids (nodes) that I loop through and change the only those objects within the state object. Rather straight forward, but updating a multidimensional array of objects and not effecting the state has me confused.

```
    UPDATE_RESTRICTION: (curState, payload) => {
    
      const updatedNodes = {...curState.layout}
      const accessProfile = BpUAE.accessProfileID
    
      payload.nodes.forEach((node, index) => {
    
    
        if (typeof (updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions) === 'undefined') {
          updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions = {};
        }
    
        if (typeof (updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions[accessProfile]) === 'undefined') {
          updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions[accessProfile] = {};
        }
    
    
        updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions[accessProfile].is_node_restricted =  JSON.parse(payload.isRestricted);

       })

    
      return {layout: updatedNodes}
    
    
    }
```

Please let me know if you need more information and thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not applying immutable update pattern correctly, you are mutating the nested references pointing into the current state object. You need to create new object references and shallow copy all state that is being updated.

```
UPDATE_RESTRICTION: (curState, payload) => {
  const updatedNodes = { ...curState.layout }
  const accessProfile = BpUAE.accessProfileID;

  payload.nodes.forEach((node, index) => {
    if (typeof (updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions) === 'undefined') {
      updatedNodes[node] = {
        ...updatedNodes[node],
        settings: {
          ...updatedNodes[node].settings,
          bp_uae_restrictions: {},
        },
      };
    }

    if (typeof (updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions[accessProfile]) === 'undefined') {
      updatedNodes[node] = {
        ...updatedNodes[node],
        settings: {
          ...updatedNodes[node].settings,
          bp_uae_restrictions: {
            ...updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions,
            [accessProfile]: {},
          },
        },
      };
    }

    // now all the new references have been created and previous
    // state shallow copied, you can update the deeply nested 
    // `is_node_restricted` property.
    updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions[accessProfile].is_node_restricted = JSON.parse(payload.isRestricted);
  });

  return {
    ...curState,
    layout: updatedNodes,
  };
}
```

UPDATE: Added the last immutable pattern

````
  const updatedNodes = { ...curState.layout }
  const accessProfile = BpUAE.accessProfileID;

  payload.nodes.forEach((node, index) => {
    if (typeof (updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions) === 'undefined') {
      updatedNodes[node] = {
        ...updatedNodes[node],
        settings: {
          ...updatedNodes[node].settings,
          bp_uae_restrictions: {},
        },
      };
    }

    if (typeof (updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions[accessProfile]) === 'undefined') {
      updatedNodes[node] = {
        ...updatedNodes[node],
        settings: {
          ...updatedNodes[node].settings,
          bp_uae_restrictions: {
            ...updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions,
            [accessProfile]: {},
          },
        },
      };
    }

    // now all the new references have been created and previous
    // state shallow copied, you can update the deeply nested 
    // `is_node_restricted` property.
    updatedNodes[node] = {
      ...updatedNodes[node],
      settings: {
        ...updatedNodes[node].settings,
        bp_uae_restrictions: {
          ...updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions,
          [accessProfile]: {
            ...updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions[accessProfile],
            is_node_restricted:  JSON.parse(payload.isRestricted)
          },
        },
      },
    };
  });

  return {
    ...curState,
    layout: updatedNodes,
  };
}```
````

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had to update it and add the last immutable pattern to the restricted key. I updated your code. Thanks

Comment: No worries. I needed your help in the right direction to go. I knew I was not getting the  immutable pattern correct and just needed to see the correct pattern to wrap my head around it. The nested part was driving me nuts..lol. Thanks again, much appreciated!

Comment: @DavidLabbe If this a case in a redux reducer, i.e. you are using redux, then I *highly* recommend looking into integrating [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) into your project. It utilizes ImmerJS under the hood and allows you to write more readable code in your reducers, similar to what you had originally wrote, it handles the immutable parts for you.

Comment: Yes I know about it but I am the type that likes to learn from the ground up. I want to fully understand how something works before replacing it with a shortcut. With that being said I am in the final stages of what is a react redux replacement with only react. So far it is working amazing and everyone says it can't be done. I may need some testers if you are interested?

Answer (score 0):

Check your return statement, you have to include your previous state and override layout like shown below.

```
 return {...curState, layout: updatedNodes}
```

Comment: I had tried that with no luck. If I console.log the curState before the loop it will show the new value that I change within the loop at this key
`updatedNodes[node].settings.bp_uae_restrictions[accessProfile].is_node_restricted =  JSON.parse(payload.isRestricted);`
That value is the same for the previous state and new.

Comment: I had tried some test and if I comment out the loop section and just add a node to the object it will then show the old and new state. Old state without the '12345' node and the new state value with the '12345' node. 

      ```UPDATE_RESTRICTION: (curState, payload) => {

    
      const updatedNodes = {...curState.layout}
      const accessProfile = BpUAE.accessProfileID
    
      updatedNodes['12345'] = true
    
      return {layout: updatedNodes}
    
    
      }```